# How do i change the style of select box options

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve the following:

[image]

I succeeded in changing the style the select box itself but not the items in it.

I have angular in my front and im using bootstrap 3 too, this is the simple code i did so far:
 HTML:

```
 < select ng-model='generator.type' class='form-control'>
                    <option class='options' value=''>Choose type...</option>
                    <option class='options' value='Multiple choice'>Multiple choice</option>
                     <option class='options' value='text box'>Text box</option>
                    <option class='options' value='just text'>Just text</option>
                    <option class='options' value='date'>Date</option>
                    <option class='options' value='video'>Video</option>
                    <option class='options' value='iframe'>Iframe</option>
                </select>
```

CSS:

```
select{
      background-color:#dddbdb;
      font-size:17px;
      color:#777676;
      line-height:1;
      background: url(../psdimages/selectarrow.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
       background-position: 98% 55%;
       -webkit-appearance: none;
  }

select .options{
    padding:20px; //just to see if it works, it doesn't...
}
```

What can i do? nothing seems to work to change anything in the inner options styling...

Comment: You can't style `option`. You will have to resort to using lists instead of `select` if you really need that kind of styling.

Comment: Would you mind showing me a simple working example of it?

Comment: you are already using bootstrap. just use that. see here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns

Comment: Its working fine for me with other styles like background-color i think its just because of the <select> tag around it that the padding/margin doesnt work in the <options> http://jsfiddle.net/6gvLtjw4/ jsfiddle with my working css

Comment: @Stefan: That is the farthest you can go with styling `option`. Just basic ones, that's it.